# Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date(2021, 9, 2) to type Logical

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to combine date and time by adding custom column with Date/Time data (e.g. 2021-09-01 18:00:00). Trying to achieve this with the following code:

`[date] and "  " and [time]`

but I end up with the error from the title. I don't see anything wrong in the formula bar:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"CreateTime naming", "Custom", each [date] and "  " and [time])`

Before I did very similar operation with date and time, using the same code phrase structure as above and it worked. Then I tried to adjust it for the mentioned operation and it failed.

The error message I get is:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date(2021, 9, 2) to type Logical.
Details:
Value=2021-09-02
Type=[Type]
```

Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: You don't use `and` for concatenating, it's `&`

Comment: If those are actual date and times, you'll need to convert to text first.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  What kind of data types are in those columns?  What kind of datatype do you expect for a result?

Comment: Also, you get that error because `and` is a logical operator, returning the logical `and` of two logical expressions.  You'd get a similar result with any non-logical argument before or after `and`

Comment: @Rory That is not the case.  No need to convert to text.  `date & time => datetime`.    Given `Value.Type(date)=>date` and `Value.Type(time)=>time` then `Value.Type(date & time)=>datetime`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld one initial column is in Date format, e.g. yyyy-mm-dd, the other in Time format but both were initially in Number format, loaded from .csv  I am trying to get from these the Date/Time data yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 in the added custom column- I just updated my question with this info, thank you for remarks.

Comment: And what happened when you made the change suggested in these comments?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld instead of "I am trying to get from these the Date/Time data yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 in the added custom column" I should have written: ".. get from these the concatenated text, that can be converted into Date/Time easily." The goal is to have the Date/Time data in one new column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld changing "and" to "&" throws this error: **Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Date and Text.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=2021-09-02
    Right= **   so Time is recognized as Text for some reason.

Comment: Did you remove the space also? Showing only part of your code, both here and in your question, makes helping you very difficult. Obviously, if time is being recognized as text you have not properly typed it earlier in the code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am sorry for that, looks I still need to work on formulating the questions. Removing space removed the error finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this discussion will clarify what I have written in the comments.

The formula to use:

```
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "datetime", 
each [date] & [time])
```

I suspect you are trying to use something like:

```
       each [date] & " " & [time])
```

which is why you see the last error you mention in your comments

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Date and Text.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=9/1/2021
    Right=
```

Had the issue been with `[Time]`, the error would have read:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Time.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left= 
    Right=1:15:00 PM
```

But the `&` operator will join a date type and a time type into a datetime type. No further conversion needed.

For example:

```
let

//data typed into a table
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSkksSVXSUSrJzE1VitWJVrLUN9Q3MjAyBIoZGlsZmkIFjWCCZlYm5uhillamRkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//data types set to date and time for the respective columns
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"date", type date}, {"time", type time}}),

//create a datetime column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [date] & [time], type datetime)

in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, issue solved. Thank you for the answer and discussion - enlightening, to me at least.